# Android: Activity.onDestroy() is not called when Dalvik kills this Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, ondestroy

I'm confused about `Activity.onDestroy()`. I need to free some resources when my Activity is destroyed, but it seems like onDestroy() is called just when i press "Back" key, but not when my Activity is killed by Dalvik. I tested it just by adding log:

`Log.v("my_tag", "onDestroy() called");`

and the same in onCreate() method too:

`Log.v("my_tag", "onCreate() called");`

Then i start my Activity, and i see in logs: `onCreate() called`. I press "Back" key and then start Activity again, then i see:

```
onDestroy() called
onCreate() called
```

Then i press "Home" key and go to my Activity again, logs does not change. All right here.

Then i press "Home" key again and start some really "heavy" applications. In logs is nothing about onDestroy(), but when i start my Activity again, i see in logs: `onCreate() called`! So, onDestroy() was not called, but my Activity was killed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) documentation:

> [..] There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's
>   hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so
>   it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

In Android, you won't get a guaranteed `onDestroy()` call.
If you want to release some resources, you should do that in `onPause()` instead.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. In the docs also stated: "The entire lifetime of an activity happens between the first call to onCreate(Bundle) through to a single final call to onDestroy()", so, I thought it should be called anyway. Well, then, where should i free resourses to be sure it will be called? Actually this `Activity` binds the `Service`, and i want to unbind it before Activity becomes destroyed.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i see that you already said: i should do it in `onPause()`. Thanks again.